# Swift equivalent of #define to retrieve list of variable arguments

Tags: swift, macros

So I have a function in C that works as

```
#define PRINTF(format) { va_list list; va_start(list, format); vprintf(format, list);}

void foo(const char* format, ...) {
   PRINTF(format)
}
```

I was wondering if I were to make a Swift equivalent of the above code, how wouldI represent the ... as? The only ways that I know how to use variable arguments is with the use of CVarArgType, or with the use of an array of arguments.

However, since this C snippet uses a macro, I'm finding it hard to port this code to Swift without changing the parameters of the function I make instead of a macro. Could I get any insight or help as to how I would go about doing something like this?

I need help to write the #define macro equivalent function in Swift, and am having trouble with coming up with an equivalent to va_list list, va_start calls.

Comment: Apple thinks (and I tend to agree) that `#define` macros make debugging harder, and as such, don't allow for them in Swift.  With that said, there's probably still a way to accept a variable number of arguments in Swift.

Comment: It’s unclear what exactly you’re asking.  Are you wanting to know how to call a C function that takes a `va_list`?  (in which case: `withVaList([1, 1.2]) { vprintf("an int: %d\na float: %f", $0) }` will work).  Or are you asking about declaring [variadic parameter functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID174) in Swift?  Or just generally, how do you `#define` macros in general in Swift?

Comment: Essentially, I need help with converting the above code to a swift equivalent. Since Swift does not allow macros, I believe I need to write a function for it instead. I'm not sure how to replicate the behavior of the above macro in Swift, specifically the va_list list, va_start calls.

Comment: Ah ok, looks like you’ve got an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), i.e. you wanted to know how to call a C var arg function, but you asked about `#define` macros.  But @nhgrif’s answer does what you need :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, my original answer absolutely overcomplicates things...

We *do* need to take a `String` for the format, and a `CVarArgType...` for the list of arguments (which as treated as a `[CVarArgType]` within the function).  I complicated it by trying to use Objective-C's `NSString`.  If we stick with Swift's `String`, it actually has an initializer which takes the arguments we're passing.

The *simplest* way to write this function in Swift looks like this:

```
func foo(format: String, args: CVarArgType...) {
    println(String(format: format, arguments: args))
}
```

---

Swift does not allow for the `#define` macro, to my knowledge.  However, we can convert that C macro to a regular Swift function.

```
func foo(format: String, args: CVarArgType...) {
    println(NSString(format: format, arguments: getVaList(args)))
}
```

`CVarArgType` is a Swift protocol which accepts the types we normally pass into the String for format strings.

The `...` makes the function accept any number of arguments for this last parameters.  Within the function, this will have the type `[CVarArgType]` (an array).

Meanwhile, `NSString`'s initializer (and similarly, `NSLog` and other similar spots) are looking for a `CVaListPointer` as the last argument, so we can use Swift's built-in function, `getVaList`, which converts a `[CVarArgType]` to a `CVaListPointer`.

This function can be called as such:

```
foo("%@, %@... %i", "hello", "world", 123)
```

Which will print:

```
hello, world... 123
```

And as @AirspeedVelocity points out, it's generally recommended to use `withVaList` rather than `getVaList`.  We can do so something like this:

```
func foo(format: String, args: CVarArgType...) {
    func buildLogString(argList: CVaListPointer) -> String {
        return NSString(format: format, arguments: argList) as String
    }
    println(withVaList(args, buildLogString))
}
```

---

For applications beyond this specific example, it's important to note that we can use the `...` to accept a list of arguments of *any* type, and within the function, we get an array of that type.

For example:

```
func bar(myVariadicListOfStuff: MyStuffClass...) {
    // myVariadicListOfStuff is a [MyStuffClass]
    for thing in myVariadicListOfStuff {
        // this is a MyStuffClass
    }
}
```

Comment: note, as the documenting comments above `getVaList` say, "Warning:: This function is best avoided in favor of `withVaList`"

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity I updated the answer... and feel like an idiot for overcomplicating it also, heh.  Look at the new top part of answer...